# How can I merge three columns into one column according to the order of in the three columns

Tags: python, r, merge, concatenation, dcast

Could you give me an advice, please?

I have three columns, e.x.:

```
x     y     z
0.2   0.5   0.26
0.75  0.58  0.25
0.78  0.86  0.95
0.56  0.75  0.52
0.45  0.47  0.57
0.2   0.58  0.98
```

Result: And I need only one column with this sequence:

```
    xyz
x1  0.2
y1  0.5
z1  0.26
x2  0.75
y2  0.58
z2  0.25
... 0.78
    0.86
    0.95
    …
```

I didn´t find a similar problem... Thank You very much. I tried to use "dcast" (R) or "concat" (Python) but I am stack.

Comment: `pandas` `pivot` is probably what you're after https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pivot a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)

Comment: @Andrew this is actually a `melt` problem, the opposite of `pivot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.melt.html) and create the row names you want with [`np.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
m = df.T.melt(value_name='xyz')
rows = np.tile(df.columns, df.shape[0])
m['variable'] = rows.tolist() + (m.variable + 1).astype(str)

    variable   xyz
0        x1  0.20
1        y1  0.50
2        z1  0.26
3        x2  0.75
4        y2  0.58
5        z2  0.25
6        x3  0.78
7        y3  0.86
8        z3  0.95
9        x4  0.56
10       y4  0.75
11       z4  0.52
12       x5  0.45
13       y5  0.47
14       z5  0.57
15       x6  0.20
16       y6  0.58
17       z6  0.98
```

And if you want is as index do:

```
m.set_index('variable')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
as.vector(unlist(t(df)))
```

This should do the trick. If you want the result by columns get rid of the `t()` operator

**edit**

Sorry I have assumed your columns belong to a `dataframe`. If this is not the case, you can create one using

```
df=cbind(x,y,z)
```

Answer (score 0):

if x, y, z are list object, you can use zip function to retrieve element
from these lists simultaneously, and use enumerate function to get the how many index in these lists.

```
for i, (a, b, c) in enumerate(zip(x, y, z)):
    print("x{} {}".format(i, a))
    print("y{} {}".format(i, b))
    print("z{} {}".format(i, c))
```

Comment: Add some explanation perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

First stack the columns and then drop the multiindex:

```
df2 = df.stack().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Now sort the values

```
print df2.sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)
```

After this you can name the column.

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- c(0.2, 0.75, 0.78, 0.56, 0.45, 0.2)
y <- c(0.5, 0.58, 0.86, 0.75, 0.47, 0.58)
z <- c(0.26, 0.25, 0.95, 0.52, 0.57, 0.98)

d <- data.frame(x,y,z)


datalist <- list()
for( i in 1:nrow(d))
{
  m <- d[i,]
  datalist[[i]] <- m
}
output <- unlist(datalist,use.names = F)
output
```

output

```
0.20 0.50 0.26 0.75 0.58 0.25 0.78 0.86 0.95 0.56 0.75 0.52 0.45 0.47 0.57 0.20
0.58 0.98
```

**Hope this will work for you.**

Regards,
Dinesh Vasu